# How do redis works to help In session persistence in window azure

Tags: azure, session, redis

When we deploy our application on cloud, and to manage the traffic we use load balancer.

Now if a user hits server 1 through load balancer, their session is created with that server, and after some time their hit is referred to server two by load balancer. Will their new session will be created again?

If this does happen, and I use redis cache to maintain their session throughout his interaction, then how does redis manage persist the session across all servers?

Comment: Redis is just a key/value cache, running independently of any of your VM's / Web Apps / cloud services. Not sure I understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I asked that once user session has been created with one server ,after some time his hit goes to another server ,each time his hit goes to different server,does it mean each time a new session will be created,or there is another scenario?. if I use redis cache to maintain server once created through user interaction.does that will be right way?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to point your application to a central Redis Cache. Your cache is running independently from your web application and all the session data for this web application will be stored in this Redis cache. Here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider) is how you can configure an ASP.NET application to use the Redis Session State provider.

Comment: My Point is that will Redis cache will support user session  when users are being handle by load balancer to manage the traffic in my application? will once session is created against one instance will be persistence through  all instance? I got your point need some detail.

Comment: If you all instances share same redis definitely the session will be shared .

Comment: The session data in any ASP.NET session-state store is associated with an ASP.NET session ID. For a particular ASP.NET Session ID, all the instances of your application should will reference the same session data (in your case from from the Redis cache).

Answer (score 0):

Redis is a key / value store. What you need to do is have the key as some unique identifier for the user session and encapsulate the session information in some object. Store this object's serialized form in the redis with the key and when a user logs in check with the key if the session exists if yes return if not then create a new one. As rightly pointed in previous answers you need to make use of centralized Redis

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install the Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider NuGet package into your app and then you can just access session in the normal way and the package will plug into Azure Redis and share your session for you.

[Detailed Instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider)

You will need to configure it in web.config with the correct data, something like this:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore" timeout="10" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" throwOnError="true" retryTimeoutInMilliseconds="1500" connectionString="myrediscache.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=thepassword,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,syncTimeout=5000" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```