# azure session management using load balancer

Tags: azure, load-balancing, session-management, azure-traffic-manager, azure-front-door

We are planning to have a web app hosted in 2 web servers in 2 different azure regions and I am planning to use either traffic manager or Azure front door for load balancing.

We want to distribute traffic based on priority so if app at one region goes down, LB can shift to other instance.

Suppose I have one instance hosted in Central US and other in Europe and using Traffic manager or Front door in India region.

I want to set Central Us instance as primary and Europe as Secondary, So LB can route traffic to Central Us and fail over to Europe in disaster.

What happens when user gets connected to Central Us region and it goes down, how does load balancer handle the session management? is it handled by load balancer automatically or any configuration needed for the same?
I do not want to go with Azure front door Sticky sessions as I want to use Priority based routing.
As traffic manager acts at DNS level, can I use it for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Priority traffic-routing method of Azure traffic manager is exactly doing the trick in your scenario.

Select Priority when you want to use a primary service endpoint for all traffic, and provide backups in case the primary or the backup endpoints are unavailable.

By default, Traffic Manager sends all traffic to the primary (highest-priority) endpoint. If the primary endpoint is not available, Traffic Manager routes the traffic to the second endpoint. If both the primary and secondary endpoints are not available, the traffic goes to the third, and so on. Availability of the endpoint is based on the configured status (enabled or disabled) and the ongoing endpoint monitoring.

[Reference: Tutorial: Configure priority traffic routing method in Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-configure-priority-routing-method)

**Update**

---

Since Azure TM works at the DNS layer, it has no way to track individual clients, and cannot implement 'sticky' sessions. If you still persist to use it for sticky sessions, you need to have an extra configuration on your web apps.

So, in this case, the Azure front door is a better-recommended method for Sticky sessions and it also supports [Priority-based traffic-routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-routing-methods#priority-based-traffic-routing).

> Each backend in your backend pool of the Front Door configuration has
> a property called 'Priority', which can be a number between 1 and 5.
> With Azure Front Door, you configure the backend priority explicitly
> using this property for each backend. This property is a value between
> 1 and 5. Lower values represent a higher priority. Backends can share
> priority values.

When you add a backend web app in the backend pool, you just need to specify the priority in the Azure front door UI.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer Nancy, My main concern is with Session management, when switching from one instance to other. As I am planning to use Priority routing, session will be created for one instance, so what happens to that session when first instance goes down and load balancer switches it to second instance.  I guess we can use Redis Cache for this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42572619/11366989

Comment: Hi, I have updated the reply, please check if you still have any question?

Comment: I agree with Priority Nancy, but it does not answer how the Sessions are managed while switching between the instances. Link I provided on the previous comment may answer the question, that is to point your application to a central Redis Cache. Thank you again!

Comment: You're correct. In the Azure front door [Session Affinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-routing-methods#session-affinity), Front Door adds a cookie to the user's session and the lifetime of the cookie is the same as the user's session. It seems does not provide session management.